# C++ Simple tree traversal and storing rows in vector's rows. Error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<int>::push_back(std::vector<int>&)'

Tags: c++, vector

```
/*performing simple tree traversal in C++ and copying tree levels node data to vector<vector<int>> rows:
Getting error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<int>::push_back(std::vector<int>&)'
*/

class Sample {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> zigzagLevelOrder(TreeNode* root) 
    {

        vector<vector<int>> result;
        zigzagLevelOrder(root, result, 0);
        return result;

    }

    void zigzagLevelOrder(TreeNode* root, vector<vector<int>>&result, int level)
    {
        if(level == result.size())
        {
            vector<int> v;
            v.push_back(root->val);    
            result[level].push_back(v);
        }
        else
        {
            result[level].push_back(root->val);
        }

        zigzagLevelOrder(root->left, result, level + 1);
        zigzagLevelOrder(root->right, result, level + 1);

    }
};
```

Comment: Which line(s) are you getting that error?

Comment: @Henri root->val is an int

Comment: @Anon: I am getting error at line: result[level].push_back(v);

Comment: @shahryarrazzak `if(level == result.size())...result[level].push_back(v);` -- This is a memory overwrite.  There is no `result[level]`, but you're accessing it.  If your goal is to do something to the last item in `result`, it is much safer to do `result.back().push_back(v);`

Answer (score 1):

`result[level].push_back(v);` - `result[level]` is a reference to `vector< int >` (though index is out of bounds), so this should be `result.push_back(v);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for all your help. Problem resolved, this is the working solution. any comments on optimizing this are welcome.

```
     struct TreeNode {
         int val;
         TreeNode *left;
         TreeNode *right;
         TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
     };

    class Sample  {

    public:
        vector<vector<int>> zigzagLevelOrder(TreeNode* root) 
        {

            vector<vector<int>> result;
            zigzagLevelOrder(root, result, 0);
            return result;

        }

        void zigzagLevelOrder(TreeNode* root, vector<vector<int>>&result, int level)
        {
            if(root != 0)
            {

                if(level == result.size())
                {
                    vector<int> v;
                    if(level%2 == 0)
                    {
                        v.push_back(root->val);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin();
                        v.insert(it, root->val);
                    }
                    result.push_back(v);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(level%2 == 0)
                    {
                        result[level].push_back(root->val);    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        vector<int>::iterator it = result[level].begin();
                        result[level].insert(it, root->val); 
                    }
                }

                zigzagLevelOrder(root->left, result, level + 1);
                zigzagLevelOrder(root->right, result, level + 1);
            }        
        }

    };
```